# How can I fire a jQuery event when scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I'm so close to having my menu figured out. I've followed the instructions given by jQuery for Designers on [Fixed Floating Elements](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/). I want to extend this by putting the Site Title above the menu I've created when you scroll.

I've got it mostly working, but when I scroll, it continues to enter the Site Title text as I scroll. I just want it to enter the site title once—basically making it look like [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/192v1J461j1r3D0x1q27). How can I run this `.before()` only one time?

Here's the fiddle I've got so far. http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/NwFc9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the scroll event correctly, but you need to add the Title only once, and then toggle it's visibility accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/NwFc9/1/

Your code is currently adding another instance of the 'Title' every time the scroll event triggers.

Main differences between the updates I made and your original:

- instantiate the Title and add it only once
- set the default display to invisible (display:none)
- toggle the visibility
- used .prepend() instead of .before() to add the title, this way it will live inside your 'fixed' menu

Comment: Awesome answer. Works perfectly. Thanks x 100000000.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event.